# Issue in regex expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of which contains 15 strings. Each of these strings ends with either .xls or .csv. These are files names in a directory. But before .xls or .csv or .xlsx, there can be any name but I need to pick only some of them. for example:

**CVAFreak_*.xls*** (anything starts with CVAFreak_ and ends with .xls)
**DSSTregk_.xlsx** (anything starts with DSSTregk_ and ends with .xlsx)
***_EOD_PNL.xls*** (anything starts with anything but ends with _EOD_PNL.xls only)
**_LEK_KIO.xlsx** (anything starts with anything but ends with _LEK_KIO.xlsx only)
**ABI_INO_*.csv*** (anything starts with ABI_INO_ & ends with .csv only)
**_UIO_TYU.csv** (anything starts with anything but ends with _UIO_TYU.csv only)
**ABC*XYZ.xls** (anything starts with ABC only and ends with XYZ only (i.e. in between ABC & XYZ anythng can come) but extension is .xls)

And three hard coded files are also in this list like **abc.xls, xyz.csv, hyg.xlsx**.

My requirement is this that I have another second list which contains hundreds of files with lots of different extensions and names but I have to choose only those file names which satisfy above criteria.

Can anyone help me in writing a Java program for this kind of requirement using regex or any other thing.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Vaibhav Read about regex and try writing your own. Then if you face some problem, paste those regex patterns here. Don't expect full baked answer.

Comment: What you have here is fileglobs, not regexes

Comment: @YatendraGoel : Yes I read Regex on a site and then I wrote down a regex pattern on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could finally answer my own question after studying Regex. I used another pattern now:

```
^(
 (.*_EOD_PNL_Explained|DailyExistingBusinessReport_.*|DailyNewBusinessReport_.*|CVA_DVA_BadValues_.*|CVA_DVA_Finance_.*)\\.csv
 |
 (CVAGreeks_.*|DVAGreeks_.*|GreekReport_CVA_HEDGEBOOK|GreekReport_CVA_LIQUID_HEDGEBOOK|WBNA_CVA_CvaGreekReport_EOD_CVA_.*|WBNA_CVA_DvaGreekReport_EOD_DVA_.*|WBNA_LIQUID_CVA_CvaGreekReport_EOD_CVA_.*|WBNA_LIQUID_CVA_DvaGreekReport_EOD_CVA_.*|WBNA_SEMI_LIQUID_CVA_CvaGreekReport_EOD_CVA_.*|WBNA_SEMI_LIQUID_CVA_DvaGreekReport_EOD_CVA_.*)\\.xls
 |
 (GreekReport_BASKET_WFCLLC_YIELDS)\\.xlsx
)$
```

https://sso.hrintouch.com/Platform/Default.aspx?ApplicationID=HRInTouch&PageID=Login&TenantID=infosysbenefits

Answer (score 3):

```
^((.*_LEK_KIO|CVAFreak_.*|hyg)\.xlsx|(DSSTregk_.*|.*_EOD_PNL|ABC.*XYZ|abc)\.xls|(ABI_INO_.*|.*_UIO_TYU|xyz)\.csv)$
```

#### Explanation

This anchors everything between `^` and `$`, meaning the start and the end of the string. This ensures that if it matches partially, it isn't a match. So `dhgSDFHKJLCVAFreak_JKLJLJKL.xslxxxx` doesn't match.

Every `|` is an OR in regex. So, in between the start and the end of the string, we have three major parts: `(...)\.xlsx|(...)\.xls|(...)\.csv` This tells us we have three alternatives: something ending in xlsx, something ending in xls, and something ending in csv.

The dot (`.`) in a regex means "any character", so if you need an actual dot, you need to escape it with a backslash, like so: `\.`. Please keep in mind that to get the backslash into a string in Java, you need to escape the backslash with another backslash, so when you're writing Java, you'll have to do `\\.`.

The star (`*`) means "repeated 0 or more times". So `.*` means "any character, repeated 0 or more times", which *really* means "any number of characters, or none at all". Please note that '.' really means *any* character, inclusing stuff like white space and unprintable characters.

Within our three major parts, we see the same mechanism we used to pick between different options. Our first major option is `(.*_LEK_KIO|CVAFreak_.*|hyg)\.xlsx`, which means "'any number of characters followed by _LEK_KIO', or 'CVAFreak_ followed by any number of characters', or 'hyg', followed by '.xlsx'". The other two are along the same lines.

---

There's your regex, I'll leave the Java to you.

Comment: Do you mind explaining it?

Comment: @EvertonAgner I was already working on it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to "or" many different cases there.
I give you a few hints:

**line starts with:**
`^start.*?`

**line ends with:**
`.*?end$`